# NextJs + Material UI, manually refreshing causes "Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "MuiTypography-root MuiLink"

Tags: material-ui, next.js

I have a Next.js project that uses Material UI, if I run the server and make changes, hot reloading works fine but if I manually refresh the page all the styles mess up and I get the `Warning: Prop className did not match. Server: "MuiTypography-root MuiLink...`

This issue has been [mentioned](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7322#issuecomment-493776864) in Next.js issues on Github, and none of the proposed solutions work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with Next.js and @material-ui.
The problem has something to do with SSR (Server Side Rendering) so you have to cancel it and remove the server side files.

step 1:
create `_document.js` under pages folder

step 2:
add this to the documents file

```
import { ServerStyleSheets } from '@material-ui/core';
import Document, { Head, Html, NextScript, Main } from 'next/document';
import React from 'react';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head></Head>
        <body>
          <Main></Main>
          <NextScript></NextScript>
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;
  ctx.renderPage = () => {
    return originalRenderPage({
      enchanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
    });
  };
  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
  return {
    ...initialProps,
    styles: [
      ...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles),
      sheets.getStyleElement(),
    ],
  };
};
```

step 3:
inside the `_app.js`
add this inside the main function component

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');
    if (jssStyles) jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles);
  }, []);
```

restart the Next.js app
and you're done

Comment: adding the hook in _app.js solved the issue.

Comment: I followed this tutorial(https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs/pages/_app.js) and It does not include something like it.